# Problem understanding a step of a short proof

Tags: calculus

I'm having some trouble understanding a step of the proof of the following theorem: if $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$ and $g$ is continuous at $c$, then $fog$ is continuous at $c$.

Proof:

Step 1: given that $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$, then there exists $\delta_1$ such that ${|f(t)-f(g(c))|}$ < $\epsilon$ when ${|t-g(c)|}$ < $\delta_1$. I have no problem with this step.

Step 2: given that $g$ is continuous at $c$, then there exists $\delta$ such that ${|g(x)-g(c)|}$ < $\delta_1$ when ${|x-c|}$ < $\delta$. I also understand this step.

Last step: what I don't understand is why it follows from steps 1 and 2 that if ${|x-c|}$ < $\delta$, then ${|f(g(x))-f(g(c))|}$ < $\epsilon$
.

Could you clarify?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x-c| < \delta$ then $|g(x) - g(c)| < \delta_1$, by step 2.

If $|g(x) - g(c)| < \delta_1$, then $|f(g(x)) - f(g(c))| < \epsilon$, by step 1 applied with $t = g(x)$.

Comment: I was kind of wondering that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A typo : 3rd last line g(c).

Answer (score 0):

The last step follows from the transitive property of implication. From the second step you have $${|x-c|} < \delta \Rightarrow {|g(x)-g(c)|} < \delta_1$$ and from the first step you have
$${|t-g(c)|} < \delta_1 \Rightarrow {|f(t)-f(g(c))|} < \epsilon$$
If we let $t=g(x)$, then we get the following chain of implications:
$${|x-c|} < \delta \Rightarrow {|g(x)-g(c)|} < \delta_1 \Rightarrow {|f(g(x))-f(g(c))|} < \epsilon$$
This gives us that $f \circ g$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought about it.